# How to export generator function in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, generator

I have this example in JS:

```
export function* mySaga () {
    yield takeEvery('USER_FETCH_REQUESTED', fetchUser);
}
```

Can I rewrite it as an arrow function in TypeScript, something like this below?

```
export const mySaga* = () {
    yield takeEvery('USER_FETCH_REQUESTED', fetchUser);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Remember that TypeScript tries, mostly, to be JavaScript-plus-types (but early-adopting newer features). There [is no arrow form of a generator function](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#prod-GeneratorDeclaration). However, Brendan Eich and Domenic Denicola are [supposed to be working on one](https://github.com/tc39/proposals).

(The TypeScript specificaton just has a placeholder for its [Generator Functions](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec.md#6.7) section [that link will rot as it's to a section *number*], and neither [the issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2873) related to implementing generators in TypeScript nor [a related pull request](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/3031) mentions an arrow form.)